# Retrieving text of select element

Tags: vue.js

When binding a `<select>` element using vue.js's `v-model`, how would you get the selected option text as opposed to the selected option value?

In HTML:

```
<select v-model="selected" options="myOptions"></select>
```

In JS:

```
myOptions: [{ text: 'Blue', value: '1' }, { text: 'Green', value: '2' }]
```

What I would want to retrieve is both the text 'Blue' as well as the value '1' by doing something like `{{ selected.text }}` or `{{ selected.value }}`. However, you can only do `{{ selected }}` which returns the selected value by default.

Ref: [Vue.js guide for Dynamic Select Options](http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Dynamic_Select_Options)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue right now. The documentation seems to imply that you can get at the `text` how you describe, but it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: According to Even You, this is not yet built into vue.js: https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/163#issuecomment-104966694

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a filter, like this:

html:

```
<div id='vm'>
    Formatted value:<b> {{city | cityFormatter}} </b><br/>
    <br/>
    <select v-model="city" options="cities"></select>
</div>
```

js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vm',
  data: {
      city: 'city1',
      cities: [{text: 'Toronto', value: 'city1'}, 
               {text: 'Orleans', value: 'city2'}]
  },
  filters: {
      cityFormatter: function(val) {
          var newVal = '';
          this.cities.map(function(el){ 
              if (val == el.value){
                  newVal = el.value + ' ' + el.text;
              }
          });
          return newVal;
      }
  }
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qfy6s9Lj/9/

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you could try combine jquery or just native js code

**The solution with jQuery**

html:

```
<div id='example'>
     <select v-model="selected" options="myOptions"></select>
</div>
```

js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
      ...
  },
   computed: {
        selectedtext:  {
            cache: false,
            //get selectedtext by jquery
            get: function(){ return $(this.$el).find(":selected").text();}
        }
    },
});
```

**The solution without jquery**

html:

```
<div id='example'>
     <select ref="ddl" v-model="selected" options="myOptions"></select>
</div>
```

js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
      ...
  },
   computed: {
        selectedtext:  {
            cache: false,
            //get selectedtext directly
            get: function(){ 
                 var ddl = this.$refs.ddl;
                 return ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Moreover, you could create a component for reusing logic and achieve the purpose of accessing the selected value by {{ selected.text }} or {{ selected.value }}.

Comment: We still have to take the text from the selected option? I was using vue as a substitute for jquery. It is really a bad :(

Comment: I think you could replace jquery code with native javascript code. It depends on what you choosing. Moreover, I think there are other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**An answer for Vue 2+**

I was interested to come across this question as I'm currently evaluating Vue and React, and  researching the comparative ease of getting current selection (not just dropdowns, but  the UI generally).

What I found was that things have changed a lot since these posts in May-July 2015, when the latest version of Vue was 0.12. The JSFiddle in @swift's answer still works today  because it pulls in Vue 0.12.

Using today's Vue, currently version 2.6, I found a solution that's relevant to people facing the same question today. It's interesting that using 2.6, the markup under discussion won't even get as far as initializing the options:

```
<select v-model="selected" options="myOptions"></select>
```

After digging into this, I found that although `options` is a valid HTML DOM property of the `select` element, and hence is accessible from JavaScript, it seems Vue no longer supports initializing it in markup like this. Instead, we add traditional HTML `option` elements. Per https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
```

On first sight, this change seems a backward step. But in fact, remembering that we can use `v-for` and `v-bind`, I think it makes things more flexible. To demonstrate why I think that, I will first show the example given at the same linked page:

HTML

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>

<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
          { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
          { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
        ]
      }
    })
```

It can be seen in the HTML that this binds the selected value of the dropdown to the Vue instance's `selected` property (using `v-model="selected"`), binds the individual option values to the `value` of each option (using `v-bind:value="option.value"`), and finally binds the individual option texts to the text that will be displayed (using  `{{ option.text }}`).

It's only a small step further to bind `selected` to a different option property, be it text, id or whatever properties your option object may have, or--and here's the thing--to the option object itself. Being able to access the option itself as the selected value means we can access all of its properties, rather than only the property we chose to bind to:

HTML

```
<div id='vm'>
    <select id="ddl1" v-model="ddl1selecteditem">
        <option v-for="option in options1" v-bind:value="option">
            {{ option.txt }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <span>selected item: text='{{ ddl1selecteditem.txt }}', id={{ ddl1selecteditem.id }}</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vm',
  data: {
    options1: [
      { txt: 'One', id: 1 },
      { txt: 'Two', id: 2 },
      { txt: 'Three', id: 3}
    ],
    ddl1selecteditem: {}
    }
});

vm.ddl1selecteditem = vm.options1[0];
```